# How to manage shared notebooks permissions in zero 2 jupyterhub deployment (kubernetes)?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub, persistent-storage

Im running jupyterhub on kubernetes using the zero 2 jupyterhub chart.
Currently i'v got persistent volume that is mounted on each single user server and is used as a shared folder. all users can read from and write to it.

The desired state is to have shared folder that will contain all user's folders in a way that each user has write permissions to his folder only.

Problems are:

1. All single user pods are run with the same user (jovian) and with the same group
2. When changing permissions to sub folders of the shared/ folder, permissions are changed in all mounted instances (eg. in all single user pods)

Is there any way to manage these permissions without managing linux users in parallel to jupyterhub user? if there isn't, are there any convenient ways (maybe some open source custom jupyterhub authenticator/single user image)that helps with it?